# postgres select query on text to array type

Tags: postgresql-9.1

in my table customer  column cc_emails datatype is text and it contains an array I want to query on my cc_emails that give result

select * from customers where cc_emails ? 'ajay@gmail.com'

```
id  name    cc_emails(Data Type Text)
1   ajay    [ajay@gmail.com,aju@gmail.com]
2   ajay12  [ajay12@gmail.com,aju12@gmail.com]
3   ajay13  [ajay13@gmail.com,aju13@gmail.com]
```

````
id  name    cc_emails(Data Type Text)
1   ajay    [ajay@gmail.com,aju@gmail.com]```
````

Comment: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should plan an upgrade to the current version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

change the data type from text to jsonb and use a query on Postgres

Comment: Postgres 9.1 did not have `jsonb`

Comment: Yes, but you tagged your question with Postgres 9.1